# What is the best way to apply a function between two named lists in R?

Tags: r, list, vectorization, named

I have an S3 object structured like this:

```
dataset <- NULL
dataset$x <- list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10), c=runif(10))
dataset$y <- list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10), c=runif(10))
```

The two lists $x and $y contain an equal number of elements with the same names.

I need to apply a function between both lists simultaneously, as follows:

```
for(i in c('a','b','c')){
  subset <- dataset$x[[i]] > 0.5
  dataset$x[[i]] <- subset(dataset$x[[i]], subset)
  dataset$y[[i]] <- subset(dataset$y[[i]], subset)
}
```

In the real case, the lists have a very large number of elements, so a loop is not the fastest approach. What is the best way to vectorize this loop?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to modify both lists in situ, then a `for` loop is really the best (clearest) way to go. As for *"fastest approach"*, generally `for` loops are as fast as `lapply` and similar (many years ago, that was not true), so there are distinct advantages to both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method with `lapply/Map`.  Extract the 'x' element from 'dataset', convert the double `list` elements to `logical` ('lst1').  Then loop over the 'dataset' with `lapply`, use `Map` inside to `subset` the inner `list` with the logical `list` created with 'x' element ('lst1')

```
lst1 <- lapply(dataset$x,`>`, 0.5)
out <- lapply(dataset, function(x) Map(subset, x, lst1))
```

The advantage is that we don't have to extract the multiple `list` elements as showed in the OP's post

-output

```
out
$x
$x$a
[1] 0.6849740 0.7275233 0.8227778 0.9315966

$x$b
[1] 0.6296180 0.5122322 0.6795041

$x$c
[1] 0.5528317 0.9408803 0.7244978 0.6040235 0.8212669 0.5369701


$y
$y$a
[1] 0.1836949 0.8954276 0.5996935 0.4948389

$y$b
[1] 0.2699243 0.5965194 0.3989432

$y$c
[1] 0.5072449 0.1735438 0.4563791 0.9464107 0.7269070 0.4369199
```